# how do I resolve an incompatible types: return error in java with arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, return-value, return-type

Here is my unfinished code. I have arrays in the phone book class and the main is calling a method to print out everything in the arrays, but there is an error.

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What would you like to do: \n 1) ADD to phone book \n 2) DELETE from phone book \n 3) CALL \n 4) PRINT phone book \n 5) quit");
    int input = myObj.nextInt();


    //constructor scanner inputs
    String ISpeedDial = myObj.nextLine();
    String Iname = myObj.nextLine();
    String Inumber = myObj.nextLine();
    //constructor
    PhoneBook b1 = new PhoneBook(ISpeedDial, Iname, Inumber);

    if (input == 1) {//add contact
// scanner saying what is the name of your new contact? what is the # of you new contact? Would you like this contact to be on your spead dails. 
//ptints your new contat is:____ and their # is ___-___-____ and the your Spead dial number is_

    }
    else if (input == 2) {//delete contact
// 
    }
    else if (input == 3) {//make call(from contact or not?)

    }
    else if (input == 4) {//print phone book
    b1.print();
    System.out.println(b1.print() + " ");
    //System.out.print(SD0[i] + " ");
    //t1.Right();//gets right triangle t/f
    //System.out.println("It is a right triangle: " + t1.Right());

    }
    else if (input == 5) {//quit
      return;
    }
    else {//invalid number
      System.out.println("invalid input: " + input);
      return;
    }

  }
}
```

PhoneBook class:

```
public class PhoneBook {

  //instance variables
  private String SpeedDial;
  private String name;
  private String number;

//Account constructor
public PhoneBook(String MSpeedDial, String Mname, String Mnumber){

SpeedDial = MSpeedDial;
name = Mname;
number = Mnumber;
}

//arrays
  String [] SD0 = new String[3];
  String [] SD1 = new String[3];
  String [] SD2 = new String[3];
  String [] SD3 = new String[3];
  String [] SD4 = new String[3];
  String [] SD5 = new String[3];
  String [] SD6 = new String[3];
  String [] SD7 = new String[3];
  String [] SD8 = new String[3];
  String [] SD9 = new String[3];

//method to deposit a specified amount into the account
public void add(){




  SD0[0] = "0";
  SD0[1] = "jo";
  SD0[2] = "123";

}

public void delete(){
  
}
//getter method to return balance
//named without void because it will return a value unlike the ones above
public String print(){
  for (int i = 0; i < SD0.length; i++) {  
    return SD0[i];  
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD1.length; i++) {  
    return SD1[i];  
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD2.length; i++) {  
    return SD2[i];  
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD3.length; i++) {  
    return SD3[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD4.length; i++) {  
    return SD4[i];  
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD5.length; i++) {  
    return SD5[i];  
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD6.length; i++) {  
    return SD6[i];  
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD7.length; i++) {  
    return SD7[i]; 
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD8.length; i++) {  
    return SD8[i];  
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SD9.length; i++) {  
    return SD9[i];  
  } 
  return;
}

}
```

My error is:

```
PhoneBook.java:76: error: incompatible types: missing return value
  return;
```

Does any one know how to fix that issue?

Also, is there a way to shorten lines(46-75) in the phone book class, of for-loops that prints each array?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are under some misconception of what the return statement actually does because the way you are using it makes little sense. e.G. Why do you loop over your SD0 array when you immediately return from the iteration? Meaning it will never go further than that first iteration and the loop is kind of pointless.

Comment: For example if your code reaches the line `return SD0[i];` the method will stop executing and return that String value. Once your method reaches a return statement that is the last statement your method will execute. Also if you tell your compiler that your method will return a value it **has to** return a value and you cannot just do `return;`

Answer (score 0):

Your last return in the print method returns nothing, when String is expected:

```
  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < SD9.length; i++) {  
    return SD9[i];  
  } 
  return;
```

You can consider using `String [][] SD = new String[10][3];` instead of having all the `SDx` as a variable

Answer (score 0):

The return statement returns immediately. It's not building a string. So your code is going to return SD0[0] as long as SD0 has length > 0.

The error is the final return with no argument at all. return "" will fix the compile error, but it probably isn't doing what you really want.